# find out if IWebBrowser2.ExecWB print was cancelled in C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, printing

I am using internet explorer to print a html document like this in C#:

```
ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT, 
SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, 
2, null);
```

This works fine, but I would like to know if the used pressed print in the dialog or cancel.

Is it possble to get this information without a ugly window hook hack ? something like a certain out parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. I had this problem and ended up testing all possible values for the last output parameter, the output parameter is not used for this command.